# Is it possible to use addToBackStack on a fragment transaction with android wear?

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os

It seems to me like addToBackStack on android wear is not working. Swiping from left to right does deliver the last Activity when not using fragments, but does not deliver the last fragment (even with addToBackStack called) when using Fragments.